# Django requesting User Name in Email template and how to move object to accept or reject folder after clicked

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have made a view that sends email through a template to an email address. I want to send the name of the user, who originally created the request but I am unable to wrap my head around it, because it's FK.

I've tried running it through a for loop and creating objects but that just prints the entirety of the data.

[admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDv9G.png)
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwVOG.jpg)

**Views.py**

```py
def accept_leave(request): #accept email
    all_item = Leave.objects.all()
    context ={'all_item':all_item }

    subject = "Leave Accepted"#email subject
    email_from = "settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER"  # email from
    to_email = ['talhamurtaza@clickmail.info']  # email to

    with open("C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/accept_email.txt", 'rb') as f:
        msgbody = f.read()
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject, body=msgbody, from_email=email_from,to=to_email)
    html_template = get_template(
        "C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/accept_email.html").render()
    msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    return render(request, 'projectfiles/email.html', context)




def reject_leave(request): #reject email
    all_item = Employee.objects.all()
    context = {'name': request.user}

    subject = "Leave Rejected"  # email subject
    email_from = "settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER"  # email from
    to_email = ['talhamurtaza@clickmail.info']  # email to

    with open(
        "C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/reject_email.txt", 'rb') as f:
        msgbody = f.read()
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject, body=msgbody, from_email=email_from, to=to_email)
    html_template = get_template(
        "C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/reject_email.html").render()
    msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
    msg.send()

    return render(request, 'projectfiles/rejectemail.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```py
class Employee(models.Model):

    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    employee_designation = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    employee_department = models.CharField(max_length = 35)


    def __str__(self):
        # return self.employee_department + " " + " "  + str(self.employee_name.username) + " " + " " + " ID: " + str(self.pk)
        return self.employee_name.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Employee"






class Leave(models.Model):
#This class will connect the user with the leave types etc and other classes data

    employee_leaves = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leave_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Leave"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.leave_Type + "  by  " + str(self.employee_leaves)
```

**email.html**

```html
<title>Email Sent</title>
{% include 'projectfiles/base2.html' %}
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class='container'>
<center>
<h3>Leave Accepted</h3>
<hr width="50%">
{{request.user}}

<br>
<br>


<h6>
<a href="{% url 'leave_show' %}"> Pending </a><strong> | | </strong><a href="{% url 'Home-Page' %}"> Home </a>
</h6>

</center>
</div>
```

**accept.html**

```html
{% include 'projectfiles/base2.html' %}


<h3>Application accepted</h3>
{{request.user}}


<h6>Have a good day</h6>
```

**adminpage.html**

```html
<title>Admin Dashboard</title>

{% include 'projectfiles/base2.html' %}

{% block asd %}
{% endblock asd %}
<br><br>

<div class="container">
<center>{% if count %}

<h3>Pending: <font color='#1783FF'> "{{ count }}"</font></h3><hr width="40%" noshade>
{% else %}
<br><br> <h2>NO LEAVES</h2>
{% endif %}</center>
</div>
<br>




{% for obj in all_items%}
<center>
<div class="container">
<h3><b>Applicant:</b> {{obj.employee_leaves}}</h3>
<b>Leave Type:</b> {{obj.leave_Type}}<br>
<small>Leave ID: {{obj.id}}</small><br>
<a href="{% url 'Accept-page' %}"> Accept</a> <b>||</b> <a href="{% url 'Reject-page' %}">Reject</a>
<hr width="50%"></center>
</div>


{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^(?i)Home/$', views.home, name='Home-Page'),
    url(r'^(?i)request/', views.request_leave, name='Leave-Page'),
    url(r'^(?i)user_dlt/', views.userdlt_page, name='userdlt-Page'),
    url(r'^password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),




    # ADMIN DASHBOARD PAGES
    url(r'^(?i)showprofile/$', views.showusers, name='Users-Page'),
    url(r'^(?i)leaves/$', views.leave_show, name='leave_show'),
    url(r'^acceptemail/$', views.accept_leave, name='Accept-page'),
    url(r'^rejectemail/$', views.reject_leave, name='Reject-page'),

    #==================




    #=========login,logout & User registration URLS=========
    url(r'^(?i)login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='projectfiles/login.html'), name='LoginPage'),
    url(r'^(?i)logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='projectfiles/logout.html'), name='LogoutPage'),
    url(r'^(?i)registraion/$', views.reg_user, name='RegPage'),
    url(r'^(?i)notifications/$', views.notifications, name='notifications-Page'),
    #=========End=========


]
```

error

```
[22/May/2019 10:21:39] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4170
[22/May/2019 10:21:46] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[22/May/2019 10:21:46] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6253
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16066
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 412
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 331
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 380
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 392
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
[22/May/2019 10:21:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[22/May/2019 10:21:52] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7492
[22/May/2019 10:21:52] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 304
[22/May/2019 10:21:52] "GET /static/js/file.js HTTP/1.1" 200 150
[22/May/2019 10:21:58] "GET /leaves/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2613
[22/May/2019 10:21:58] "GET /static/js/login.js HTTP/1.1" 200 293
[22/May/2019 10:22:05] "GET /acceptemail/4/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /acceptemail/4/




<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">





    <style>
      body {
  background-color:
[22/May/2019 10:22:05] "GET /acceptemail/4/%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C!doctype%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%3E%0A%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3C!--%20Required%20meta%20tags%20--%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1,%20shrink-to-fit=no%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3C!--%20Bootstrap%20CSS%20--%3E%0A%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%0A%20%20%20%20integrity=%22sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22/static/css/styles.css%22%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20body%20%7B%0A%20%20background-color: HTTP/1.1" 404 6369
```

new view

```py
def accept_leave(request, id):  # accept email
    all_item = Leave.objects.get(id=id)
    context ={'all_item': all_item}

    subject = "Leave Accepted"#email subject
    email_from = "settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER"  # email from
    to_email = ['talhamurtaza@clickmail.info']  # email to

    with open("C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/accept_email.txt", 'rb') as f:
        msgbody = f.read()
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=subject, body=msgbody, from_email=email_from,to=to_email)
    html_template = get_template(
        "C:/Users/Bitswits 3/Desktop/Intern Work/LMS/LMS/projectfiles/templates/projectfiles/email/accept_email.html").render()
    msg.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
    msg.send()

    html = render_to_string(
        "projectfiles/email/accept_email.html", {'all_item': all_item})

    return HttpResponseRedirect(html)
```

I want the requesting user's name and some other info such as what type of leave he chose to pass in the email template and be sent.
and can you please guide me as to what approach to take if I want the one object to move to a done status from its pending as shown in the adminpage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npl4t.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code:

1. Your view `accept_leave` is not receiving the applicant's name. Your 'accept' button shouldn't be a link to `accept_leave` (a GET request), but you should create a form for each of the applicants and the 'accept' button should submit the form (as a POST request) with the applicant's id (or username, something unique) in the URL or as an input field. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) to learn how to work with forms.

   Alternatively, if you really want to use GET, and not use a form, change the URL of your `accept_leave` view to also have the applicant id (`/acceptemail/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$`) and pass the id to your url constructor in the template (`{% url 'accept-page' id=obj.id %}`)
2. Once you have passed the applicant id to your view, you'll retrieve it with `employee = Employee.objects.get(id=...)` and you can use that object to fill in what you need to send the email (but also to create the `Leave` object for that employee).
3. You want to render your templates with Django's template rendering engine, so you can pass context variables to your template (e.g. `employee`) and use them in your email templates (e.g. `{{ employee.name }}`). You can do that with [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), e.g.:

   ```
   html = render_to_string("projectfiles/email/accept_email.html", {'employee': employee})
   text = render_to_string("projectfiles/email/accept_email.txt", {'employee': employee})
   ```

   to then use `html` and `text` to send the email.

Comment: I am using html and text. but how do I pass the requesting user name etc?

Comment: "requesting" is the `Employee` object, no? My answer shows how to pass `employee` to the template, so inside the email.html you can then use `{{employee.name}}`.